# SQL Find and Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have name of client and name of doctor. I want to get there ID from DB and insert IDs into table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddMedicalCard
@Client nchar,
@Doctor nchar
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Clients.[ClientCode] AS [Code]
    Into #NewClientCode
    FROM Clients
    WHERE Clients.[ClientName]=@Client

    SELECT Personal.[DoctorCode] AS [Code]
    Into #NewDoctorCode
    FROM Personal
    WHERE Personal.[DoctorName]=@Doctor

    INSERT INTO MedicalCard 
        VALUES (#NewClientCode.[Code].First, #NewDoctorCode.[Code].First)

    DROP TABLE #NewClientCode
    DROP TABLE #NewDoctorCode
END
GO
```

Errors:

> *The multi-part identifier "#NewDoctorCode.Code.First" could not be bound.
>
>   The multi-part identifier "#NewClientCode.Code.First" could not be bound.
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

MedicalCard table design:

```
RecordingCode(Key), ClientCode, DoctorCode
```

and 5 other nullable columns.

Comment: First of all: if you use any string-related type as a parameter - **always** specify a length! Otherwise your string will be exactly **1 character long**! Secondly: why `nchar`? That really only makes sense if you have a fixed length string - e.g. a 3-character currency code or something like that. Otherwise, I would **always** use `nvarchar(x)` for a variable-length string.

Comment: Also: why even use temporary tables?? You're only retrieving a single value - just store those into SQL variables and use those variables in the `INSERT` statement... using **two** temporary tables for this is awfully inefficient and a total overkill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message says it all. There is no such thing as `#NewDoctorCode.Code.First`. Your job can be easily & cleanly done as follows.

**Note:** It is not very correct to get clientcode and doctorcode by their names as there could be more than 1 client & doctors with the same name.

```
--declare two variables 
declare @clientCode varchar(50), @doctorCode varchar(50)

--assign clientCode
SELECT TOP 1   @clientCode = Clients.[ClientCode]
FROM Clients
WHERE Clients.[ClientName]=@Client

--assign doctorCode
SELECT TOP 1  @doctorCode = Personal.[DoctorCode]
FROM Personal
WHERE Personal.[DoctorName]=@Doctor

--finally insert them to MedicalCard table
INSERT INTO MedicalCard (clientCodeColumn,doctorCodeColumn) --Column Names
VALUES (@clientCode,@doctorCode)
```

Comment: I have just edited to add `TOP 1`. Also please read my `note`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT @i = id FROM youtable;
BEGIN
    Insert into tablename(column1) values(@i)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should use variables and not table. If you use table then you should use `insert into table select col`

```
DECLARE @NewClientCode int
DECLARE @NewDoctorCode int

SELECT @NewClientCode = Clients.[ClientCode]
FROM Clients
WHERE Clients.[ClientName]=@Client

SELECT @NewDoctorCode = Personal.[DoctorCode]
FROM Personal
WHERE Personal.[DoctorName]=@Doctor

INSERT INTO MedicalCard 
    VALUES (@NewClientCode, @NewDoctorCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddMedicalCard
@Client nchar,
@Doctor nchar
AS
BEGIN




    INSERT INTO MedicalCard 
        VALUES (
                SELECT TOP 1 Clients.[ClientCode]
                FROM Clients
                WHERE Clients.[ClientName]=@Client,

                SELECT TOP 1 Personal.[DoctorCode]
               FROM Personal
               WHERE Personal.[DoctorName]=@Doctor
              )


END
GO
```

Comment: **Always** define a **length** on your string parameters! Otherwise they end up being **1 character** long....